# QwtPlot - How to customize the footer?

Tags: qt, qwt

[image: QwtPlot]

What is the meaning of the label in the yellow rectangle? How to remove (hide) it?

I'm working with Qwt 6.0.1 and Qt 4.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found, looking deep in the code, that the label is not part of a standard QwtPlot. It's a custom label and it's created using the following method of the QwtText class:

```
void draw( QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect ) const;
```

Pseudo-code:

```
void MyQwtPlot::drawCustomLabel()
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QwtText label(<label-text>);
    label.draw(&painter, QRectF(<label-position>));
    painter.end();
}
```

where MyQwtPlot is a class that extends QwtPlot.

I've solved commenting the drawCustomLabel method in my implementation.

Comment: So you propose editing QwtPlot source? It's probably not the best solution. If the text is implemented using custom label, it's better to change that custom implementation (which unfortunately is not included neither in the question nor in the answer). So, as it currently stands, I don't see any way this can help future visitors.

Comment: I've fixed my answer introducing the pseudo-code for the generation of a custom label in a QwtPlot. Thanks for your help.